# Is it possible to get the entire json used to load a dijit.tree from the tree store?

Tags: javascript, dojo

i am loading a dijit.tree using the store using url

```
var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({
    url: "JsonFiles/data.json"
});
```

is it possible to get the entire json from this tree store?

Comment: Maybe I've got it wrong, but the idea of JsonRestStore and similar is to fetch only portions of data. If you want to fetch once and process in memory, you should use MemoryStore.